# Can I embed a YouTube Video without an indication it's from YouTube?

Tags: youtube-api

There are a few unlisted Videos and Live Streams that I'd like to host on my website but I don't want any type of indication showing that the video originated from YouTube. What are my options? I want to hide Watch Later, Share, and Copy Link as well as disabling clicking the title to end up on the watch page.

Are there options for the embedded? Can I get the video/stream it self and throw it into a custom player?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer but , you can extract video URL of exact video format like mp4_720p with some third party libraries like **`ytdl`** and then play that stream url in a custom video player on your site.

Comment: Was a great answer, not quite what I need but thank you for it! :)